# Cannot connect to Oracle Cloud instance vie SQL Developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am on macOS Big Sur, using SQL Developer.
I have created and used my cloud instance in a Spring Boot app, but I cannot connect via SQL Developer. For the app, I have a configuration which uses the same wallet.
Furthermore, I have followed the below:

[Download the wallet *which is OK](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-download-wallet.html#GUID-B06202D2-0597-41AA-9481-3B174F75D4B1)

[Connect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-sql-dev182.html#GUID-14217939-3E8F-4782-BFF2-021199A908FD)

I don't have the option for high, low, medium etc.
[image: New Database Connection]

[Already tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059765/how-to-connect-oracle-cloud-instance-using-oracle-cloud-shell)

The database version is 19c. It is not necessary to connect via SQL Developer, another tool would do the work too.

Thanks!

Comment: When you click the drop-down...it's empty?

Comment: Another tool may be web SQL Developer, which is accessible via Tools -> Database Actions -> SQL. But try to open your `Wallet_***.zip`, locate `tnsnames.ora` in it and check if there are high, medium and low entries.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith yup. It is empty.

Comment: @astentx The tnsnames.ora is included.

Comment: Where did you put the file? Guessing sqldev/java can't read it